# How to add two <script> tag in one variable?

Tags: javascript, php, script-tag

I am using one variable to fetch the text file content, where the text file will contain the HTML element

Example: test.txt

```
<main>
  <div> Example </div>
  <script async src="https://example.com/js/abc.js"></script>
  <script>(some inner text);</script><br>
</main>
```

To fetch the txt file

`var contents = '<?php print file_get_contents('abc/test.txt'); ?>'; document.getElementById('replace_contents').innerHTML = htmlCode;`

But I got an error in the console like [image]

If i check that deep it will show an error in   `<script async src="https://example.com/js/abc.js"></script>` and it does not show the second `<script>` tag..

Even i tried this separate [image]

In the above picture you can see `</script>`  is not considered as a variable.

I don't know what is causing this.
Please help me find an answer to this problem...

Comment: seems correct - you are getting javascript error on `(some inner text);`

Comment: Please share more details. How does the generated markup look like? " i will show an error in" - what does that mean?

Comment: No @FlashThunder, i am not getting an error on `(some inner text);`

Comment: @NicoHaase, my bad, it's " it will show an error in"

Comment: btw `var contents = '<?php print file_get_contents('abc'/test.txt'); ?>'; ` is incorrect syntax ... `'abc'` part is ending the quoting... so you are generally getting PHP error message, that contains quotes as well ... use `addslashes()` or `htmlentities()` and change `...('abc'/test.txt')` to `...('abc/test.txt')`

Comment: @FlashThunder Thank you for making me correct. but `('abc'/test.txt')` is not the problem. In my code, it is `('abc/test.txt')` only.
I tried both addslashes() or htmlentities() like `<?php print htmlentities(file_get_contents('abc/test.txt')); ?>';`  and `'<?php $output file_get_contents('abc/test.txt'); print htmlentities($output); ?>';`. But it returns empty value `''` but my file has content. @FlashThunder am i missing something?

Comment: the path could be incorrect and I guess no one really uses `print` in `PHP`, but `echo`... try this to check: `echo (int)file_exists('abc/test.txt');` does it return 0 or 1?

Comment: @FlashThunder, yes, I checked this with both echo and print, it returns 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `\` at the end of the line to allow the string to include the following line. Because Javascript is not like PHP, strings don't automatically include next lines.

For example :
Instead of ...

```js
var lines = 'here is the first line
but the second line is not included'; // Error

You can write...

var lines = 'here is the first line\
and now the second line is included'; // Correct

Or use the + operator

var lines = 'here is the first line' +
'and I add the second line'; // Correct
```

Comment: That's not enough, unfortunately. HTML parser will consider the "</script>" part of the string to be the closing tag for the script element the script is contained in.

Comment: @amn yes, I tried what you said in a different ways, but it did not solve the problem. Even i added `<br>` to the text file, but I am getting same error

Answer (score -1):

you can't use more than 1 `<script></script>` in another script tag.

Comment: Please share more details. What does that mean? Why should even one `<script>`  tag be allowed within another `<script>`  tag?

Comment: @NicoHaase if you see the above code, you will understand, one `<script>` tag is not inside the other